# slide out/up panel when Hovering LinkButton and cannot reach content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make Panel SlideDown/SlideUp upon hovering LinkButton the Panel is just below the LinkButton.The problem is that when i hover the HButton3 it continuesly slides up and down and when i try to reach the content inside AccomodationPanel the panel slides up so my question is how to make the content in AccomodationPanel reachable so the panel does not close

Jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#StayOpen").hover(

                    function () {
                        $("#AccomodationPanel").slideDown(1000);
                    }, function () {
                        $("#AccomodationPanel").slideUp(1000);
                    });   
                });
```

HTML :

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="StayOpen" style ="z-index:10;height:auto">
               <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Hbutton3" CssClass="HButton" >

               </asp:LinkButton>

               <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="AccomodationPanel" style ="position:absolute;left:60vw;width:20vw;top:10vh;background-color:#FFD6AD;z-index:11;display:none;height:auto"  >
                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen1" CssClass="StayOpen">ASD</asp:LinkButton>
                   <br />
                     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen2" CssClass="StayOpen">ZZZ</asp:LinkButton>
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="StayOpen3" CssClass="StayOpen">GGG</asp:LinkButton>
               </asp:Panel>
                   </asp:Panel>

           </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: use `.stop() `  in jquery

Comment: your code be  `$("#AccomodationPanel").stop(true,true).slideToggle(1000);`

Comment: can you write the whole Jquery I need to rewrite